# How to add Button in Magenot 2 Sales order Grid with out a link?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, order-grid, custom-button

I want to add a button without a link at the sales grid top in Magento 2.4
SS:

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to add only a button with a custom ( ID or class ).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="buttonuniquename" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\CustomButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/CustomButton.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * CustomButton constructor.
     *
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
          
        return [
            'label' => __('Your Button Name'),
            'on_click' => 'javascript:void(0)',
            'class' => 'your custom classs',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @M2DeV
I have added button with same scenario but on clicking that button it redirect to dashboard.
I don,t want redirection i just want a normal button.

Comment: added `'on_click' => 'javascript:void(0)'` in answer hope it work for you

Comment: Thanks for your response Can I add multiple button's here ?

Comment: yes you can any number of

Comment: can you please provide any example.

Comment: in `sales_order_grid.xml` you can add multiple `<button>` tag with each separate class for each button.

Answer (score 1):

Just add javascript:void(0) in getUrl(), Try Like this.

```
/**
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        if ($id = $this->container->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $data = [
                'class' => 'action-secondary scalable delete',
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'on_click' => "deleteConfirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete This Profile ?','" . $this->getDeleteUrl($id) . "')",
                'sort_order' => 20,
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'url' => $this->getDeleteUrl()
                ],
            ];
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return 'javascript:void(0)';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'on_click' => 'javascript:void(0)' to your button data array.

For example your array could be something like below

```
public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Custom Button 1'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'on_click' => 'javascript:void(0)'
        ];
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that above example for ui_component-> grid.xml file
ex:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_grid.custom_grid_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_grid.custom_grid_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_grid_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

You can add more buttons similarly and provide url where you want to redirect or make it like above